# How to make multiple file .txt from spesific column in data frame

Tags: r, write.table

I have a data frame that contained 2 Column, DOCS and TEXT

```
DOCS    TEXT
1   tanaman jagung seumur jagung 
2   tanaman jagung kacang ketimun rusak dimakan kelinci 
3   ladang diserbu kelinci tanaman jagung kacang ketimun rusak dimakan 
4   ladang diserbu kelinci tanaman jagung kacang ketimun rusak dimakan 
5   ladang diserbu kelinci tanaman jagung kacang ketimun rusak
```

I want to make multiple files .txts as many as the number of id and every file containing the different contents (every 1 txt file containing 1 row text in a column of TEXT). So if i have 5 Docs-> 5 file .txt with different content

I have already tried this code

```
for (j in 1:nrow(dataframe)) {
         mytitle <- format("docs")
         myfile <- file.path(getwd(), paste0(mytitle, "_", j, ".txt"))
         write.table(dataframe$TEXT, file = myfile, sep = "", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE,
                     quote = FALSE, append = FALSE)
        }
```

but, the results was contained 5 file.txt which each file has same content that contained all rows in column 'TEXT'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try the following also instead of using for loops that may confuse you

```
# Create a data frame 
DOCS <- c(1:5)
TEXT <- c("tanaman jagung seumur jagung " , 
          "tanaman jagung kacang ketimun rusak dimakan kelinci" , 
          "ladang diserbu kelinci tanaman jagung kacang ketimun rusak dimakan" , 
          "ladang diserbu kelinci tanaman jagung kacang ketimun rusak dimakan" , 
          "ladang diserbu kelinci tanaman jagung kacang ketimun rusak ")

df <- data.frame(DOCS , TEXT , Test)

# Convert to matrix 
M <- as.matrix(df)

# Create a function that will write every single file
write_file <- function(file){
  my_title <- format("docs")  
  file_name <- file.path(paste0( my_title , "_" , file[1] , ".txt"))
  file_content <- file[2]
  write.table(file_content , file = file_name , append = F , row.names = F 
  , col.names = F , quote = F)

}

# Use the apply function to pass each row in matrix to the 
# function that creates every single file

apply(M , 1 , write_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that each file contains the same is that you write the whole TEXT column every time. The following code produces 5 different files:

```
 for (i in 1:nrow(dataframe)) {
       myfile <- file.path(paste0("docs_", i, ".txt"))
       file.cont <- strsplit(dataframe$TEXT[i]," ")
       write.table(file.cont, file = myfile, sep = "", row.names = FALSE,
                   col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
 }
```

As you see, I create the file contents by picking the `i`th row from the data frame (`dataframe$TEXT[i]`). Then I split the string up into several strings using `strsplit`. This ensures that each word will printed on its own line.

Also I create the file name differently from you. I don't understand your use of `format()`. I put everything into one line. There is no need to include `getwd()` into the path, because R will write in your working directory anyways.